# Difference between ANT 1.7.0 and ant 1.9.1 versions

Tags: ant

I want to know where to find the differences between different versions of ant?
  Currently I am using ant 1.7.0 for running my system testcases.I want to migrate to new ant  version 1.9.1. After migrating I want to make sure that my testcases are compatible with ant 1.9.1 version

Comment: Have you checked the changelog?

Comment: check this[http://ant.apache.org/antnews.html

Answer (score 0):

Get it here [ant](http://ant.apache.org/antnews.html). Which will explain which ant was released with which extensions..